# How to track Akka Messaging

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

I am using Akka cluster with Master-Worker Pattern to distribute jobs to worker nodes. Kafka and JMS messaging has API to browse messages in the queue or topics. May I know what are the best practices to track messages in Akka systems among all senders and receivers so I can effectively trouble shooting ?  Is there any framework built upon Akka to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable actor-level logging for all received messages and actor lifecycle state changes:

```
akka {
  loglevel = "DEBUG"
  stdout-loglevel = "DEBUG"
  loggers = ["akka.event.Logging$DefaultLogger"]

  // log-config-on-start = on
  log-dead-letters = 10
  log-dead-letters-during-shutdown = on

  actor {
    debug {
      receive = on
      autoreceive = on
      lifecycle = on
      unhandled = on
    }
  }
}
```

For it to work, all your actors need to extend ActorLogging trait and also receive() method in actors needs to be tweaked a bit:

```
def receive: Receive = LoggingReceive {
  // message handlers go here 
}
```